# How to make font size variables in x axis smaller

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have this code to create a bar plot, but I want to change the names in the x axis to species names for example, and I would like to make the font smaller so that I can fit it all in. I ave tried using the cex function in various combinations, but has not worked. I would be grateful for a suggestion?

```
    count <-     
    matrix(c(16,102,11,106,15,95,26,87,18,99,21,103,12,110,30,103,10,107,20,87,13,110,17,93),     nrow = 2)  


    barplot(count, beside=T, legend =T, ylim=c(0,130),
    col=c("darkolivegreen3", "firebrick1"), 
    ylab="Frequency (no. of moths)", las = 3, 
    names = c("tiger\nCo", "tiger\nCr" , "eyes\nCo", "eyes\nCr", "mottled\nCo","mottled\nCr",  "pepperL\nCo","pepperL\nCr", "pepperD\nCo","pepperD\nCr", "convol\nCo", "convol\nCr"))        


    legend(6,130, legend=(c("survived","predated")), pch=c(15,22), cex=0.8,    col=c("darkolivegreen3","firebrick1"))
```

Comment: `cex` is never a function in my experience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, according to the `?barplot` page there is a `cex.names` argument:

```
barplot(count, beside=T, legend =T, ylim=c(0,130),
    col=c("darkolivegreen3", "firebrick1"), 
    ylab="Frequency (no. of moths)", las = 3, 
    cex.names=0.8,
    names.arg = c("tiger\nCo", "tiger\nCr" , "eyes\nCo", "eyes\nCr", 
                   "mottled\nCo","mottled\nCr",  "pepperL\nCo", 
                   "pepperL\nCr", "pepperD\nCo","pepperD\nCr", 
                    "convol\nCo", "convol\nCr"))        
    legend(6,130, legend=(c("survived","predated")), pch=c(15,22),    
                          col=c("darkolivegreen3","firebrick1"))
```

I admit that finding the right cex.* argument is sometimes difficult and sometimes requires separate calls to axis, but here it seems nigh unto trivial.