# Change font size of each column in simple bar plot so that all labels are visible?

Tags: r, plot

Here is the code that I used to create the table

```
barplot(sort(table(df$Department_lower), decreasing=TRUE))
```

Here is a sample of the table data

[image: sample data picture]

Here is the result. We need labels for all columns to be visible

[image: The bar chart looks good but you cannot see the column name for all 9 levels]

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: just added a screenshot of the data. The output of dput(df) is way too large

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to make font size variables in x axis smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367231/how-to-make-font-size-variables-in-x-axis-smaller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be rotation the labels of your x-axis using `las = 2`. I created some extra random labels to give you a reproducible example. First a before plot:

```
df <- data.frame(Department_lower=sample(c('labelA', 'entrees', 'salad', 'labelB', 'general', 'catering', 'swag', 'labelC', 'labelD'),
                                   50, replace=TRUE))

plot <- barplot(sort(table(df$Department_lower), decreasing=TRUE))
```

Before:

[image]

Rotating x-axis labels:

```
plot <- barplot(sort(table(df$Department_lower), decreasing=TRUE), las = 2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Ihc0003, No problem. Check this post for more options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981929/how-to-display-all-x-labels-in-r-barplot